# golang websocket.JSON.Receive invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of value

Tags: json, go, websocket

**ERROR while receiving JSON data via websockets**

**invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of value**

I am using "golang.org/x/net/websocket" package

I have a Message struct:

```
type Message struct {
    Sender     *Client `json:"sender",omitempty`
    Sendername string  `json:"senderName"`
    Message    string  `json:"message"`
}
```

And the code that i am using for receiving on server is:

```
var err error

    for {
        reply := Message{}
        if err = websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &reply); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Cannot receive " + err.Error())
            break
        }

        fmt.Println(reply)
}
```

And the JSON string I am passing is

```
{"senderName":"CJ","message":"DATA"}
```

Client side:

```
let msg = document.getElementById("message").value             
let obj = { senderName : "CJ", message : msg}             
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))             
sock.send(msg);
```

I am not able to figure out the error, I think it is regarding the JSON data.

Comment: I think it is not receiving JSON remove JSON parser and read message as plain text on server to see what is actually being received

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I  converted reply to string and tried using websocket.Message.Receive the output was "DATA".

Comment: Maybe you can try: `var data []byte; websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &data); fmt.Printltn(string(data))` to see the data that is received

Comment: @edkeveked I tried it its just receiving 4 bytes [100 97 116 97]
The  code at client side for sending data is `let msg = document.getElementById("message").value
            let obj = {
                senderName : "CJ",
                message : msg,
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
            sock.send(msg);`

Comment: `msg` is a string since `document.getElementById("message").value` returns a string. If you rather want to sent `obj`, it should rather be `sock.send(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: Now you can use `websocket.JSON.Receive` instead, I mean your initial code

Comment: Thanks @edkeveked, It works now I forgot to send the Stringified object I get it now(A silly mistake by me) :)

Comment: See my answer below. You can accept it and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the data sent by the client. That data is likely not a json data.

The client is currently sending `document.getElementById("message").value` which is a string and not a json data.

The client code should be modified as follows:

```
sock.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
```